# Unscramble a string with wildcards compared with a set of available options in PHP

Tags: php, pattern-matching, wildcard, string-matching

For a side-project I wondered what the best approach would be for the following:

I have a given list of strings and I have a string that contains the shuffled characters of one of the words in the list.
As an added challenge the shuffled string might contain wildcards ('*').

What would be a way to unscramble the string against the available words?
I tried looping through it and use fnmatch(), which works with wildcards, but it doesn't work with scrambled strings.
I came across the method count_chars, that I could possibly use, but that doesn't work with wildcards I believe.
Performance isn't really an issue, given the list of words is pretty small, but still, faster is better obviously.

**Edit**

This is what I tried:

```
$pattern = 'Pe*r';
$words = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Peach'];
fnmatch('Pe*r', $words[$1], FNM_CASEFOLD); // returns 1
fnmatch('ea*r', $words[$1], FNM_CASEFOLD); // returns 0
```

And I've tried the count_chars solution found here:
[compare scrambled words with an unscrambled wordlist php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1936509/compare-scrambled-words-with-an-unscrambled-wordlist-php) - but I'm puzzled on how to combine that with fnmatch to include the wildcard option.

Thanks in advance for any offered explaination or push in the right direction.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow questions should almost always contain code of what you've tried and where your issue lies.

Comment: ignore that you have words? sort the characters into alphabetic order, e.g. `alphabetic -> aabcehilpt`, then you can use fnmatch. of cousre that kinda loses the wildcards, but...